# Java Properties class bug

Tags: java

I have this piece of code.

```
// On a thread
try {
    WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    Path directory = Paths.get("properties");
    WatchKey watchKey = directory.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
    while (true) {
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
            Path changed = (Path) event.context();
            if (changed.toString().equals("radar.properties")) {
                System.out.println("read call:");
                readProperties();
            }

        }

        if (!watchKey.reset()) {
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    FCSLogger.LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception while setting up WatchService", e);
}

// Method called by the above code

private void readProperties() {
    try {
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(Paths.get("properties", "radar.properties").toString());
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(input);
        updateRate = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("updateRate"));
        System.out.println(updateRate);
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It returns the right result on the first call and then blocks the whole thread. I've isolated the bug to be in this method since everything else works flawlessly when there is no calling this method. I'm wondering what am I doing wrong here.
Snapshot of console output:

```
// First change of file:
read call:
10
read call:
10

// Second change of file:
read call:

// I keep changing but nothing happens:
```

Comment: If you could boil your code and bug down to a reasonable [mre], you'll likely increase your odds of getting a decent answer quickly.

Comment: That's still not a [mcve] - it's not something we can compile and run.

Comment: Please check out the link that is in @JonSkeet's comment and in mine as it will explain what we're requesting and why creating one can help you 1) get an answer here, or 2) more easily discover the source of the problem yourself

Comment: You look to be using a never-ending tight loop to continually poll properties -- why?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I need to update the updateRate whenever there is a change in file - I couldn't come up with something different

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the use of WatchService, but most examples I've seen ([e.g.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)) a WatchKey is assigned *inside* the loop using the `.take()` method. This looks to be a blocking method and so is done in a background thread. I think that this would block the loop until a change occurs, preventing stealing CPU cycles needlessly.

Comment: I've edited the code so that I take the key inside the loop. I get the exact same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be that `readProperties` throws `NumberFormatException`, and that causes your watcher thread to exit.

You could wrap calls to `readProperties` and catch exceptions; so that at least the watcher will keep watching in case of exceptions.

And you should use `take`, so that the watcher thread blocks. Your current solution causes 100% cpu usage.

See below the modified code. I added a writer thread to update the file, and (unsurprisingly?) `readProperties` can fail since we are accessing the file while it is being written. A possible output is:

```
....
property=5000
property=null
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
  at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:614)
  at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
  at cl.ClientPoll.readProperties(ClientPoll.java:26)
  at cl.ClientPoll.run(ClientPoll.java:46)
property=6000
property=7000
....
```

---

So when watching, you can either: skip on error and continue; or use other APIs so that the file being written is locked while writing.

---

Sample code

```
package cl;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ClientPoll extends Thread {
  private void readProperties() {
    try {
      Path path = Paths.get("radar.properties");
      InputStream input =new FileInputStream(path.toString());
      Properties prop = new Properties();
      prop.load(input);
      String property = prop.getProperty("updateRate");
      System.out.println("property="+property);
      int updateRate = Integer.parseInt(property);
//      System.out.println(updateRate);
      input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
      Path directory = Paths.get(".");
      WatchKey watchKey = directory.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
      while (true) {
        WatchKey wk = watcher.take();
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents()) {
          Path changed = (Path) event.context();
          if (changed.toString().equals("radar.properties")) {
            try {
              readProperties();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
          }
        }
        if (!watchKey.reset()) {
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ClientPoll().start();
    new Writer().start();
  }
}

class Writer extends Thread {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        File f = new File("radar.properties");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
        fw.write("updateRate="+i*1000);
        fw.close();
        sleep(1000L);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    System.out.println("exit");
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: It was NumberFormatException in checkProperties. Thanks.